fputcsv adds "," in new line
I export data to csv. I've searched a lot, the issue remains. for testing I creaded this array:
$daten[] = "HEAD1,HEAD2,HEAD3\n";
$daten[] = "VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3\n";

I export to csv via
$fp = fopen('path_to/filename.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $daten, ",", '"',"\", "\n" );

the resulting csv looks in the editor a little different thatn expected:
"HEAD1,HEAD2,HEAD3
","VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3
"
So the file starts and ends with the " and each new line is welcomed with ","
I used just
fputcsv($fp, $daten) 

=> same result
tried \n\r for the data => same result

fputcsv() should be used to format a single line in a CSV file. You should feed it the column values in an array. This is not what you do. You feed it two actually lines in an array and expect it to create a multi-line CSV file out of that. Just read the manual, en the example there, to see how to use it properly.

thank you. sure, you're right. how could I?

This is not an array, this is a string that is already formatted to look like a CSV:
$daten[] = "HEAD1,HEAD2,HEAD3\n";

This string is treated as one single column value. PHP doesn't know that you want to treat these as separate values.
If you have:
$daten[] = "one";
$daten[] = "two";

And then fputcsv($daten), you'll get the two values separated by commas:
one,two

Your example already has commas in it, so they have to be escaped by quoting the string. You end up with one row that has two columns, where each column is itself long comma-separated string -- because that's exactly what you passed in.
"HEAD1,HEAD2,HEAD3\n","VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3\n"

If you want two rows of three columns each, you need to call fputcsv() once per row, passing in an array of columns each time:
fputcsv($fp, ['HEAD1', 'HEAD2', 'HEAD3']);
fputcsv($fp, ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3']);

This will give you the (presumably) desired result:
HEAD1,HEAD2,HEAD3
VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3

